A translation question about Colossians 1:27
I stumbled onto answers to a question about the meaning of "ἡ ἐλπὶς
τῆς δόξης" which turned out not to answer my very straightforward linguistic question, which is strictly about the translation of the phrase. Is "ἡ ἐλπὶς τῆς δόξης" necessarily translated "the hope of glory" or could it be translated "the glorious hope"?
[I feel I might need to stipulate that I myself really am only interested in the linguistic aspect of this question.]
Colossians 1:27 SBL Greek New Testament

οἷς ἠθέλησεν ὁ θεὸς γνωρίσαι τί τὸ πλοῦτος τῆς δόξης τοῦ μυστηρίου τούτου ἐν τοῖς ἔθνεσιν, ὅ ἐστιν Χριστὸς ἐν ὑμῖν, ἡ ἐλπὶς τῆς δόξης ·


If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you might also ask on the Latin.SE site, which despite its name also accepts questions about classical and biblical Greek: Can we make NT Greek on-topic now? - Latin Language Meta Stack Exchange.

I think, "The glorious hope" is close to the meaning, but I would suggest a translation of “the hope for this glory” is more accurate.  "The glorious hope" focuses the topic on 'hope' and not on 'glory' which I think is Paul's intent.  So, your question really is one of the linguistics behind the focus?
I’ll offer a linguistic observation and a syntactic one.  The first is actually based in cognitive linguistics.  That is, it refers to how the mind processes language.
When the expression,  τῆς δόξης, is seen, we’ve already seen δόξα in the very close context, a mere few words before.  What that means in the mind is that the neurons associated with the meaning of δόξα are already turned on.  You’ve seen this type of thing in your own life, I’m sure, when you’ve been able to complete someone else’s sentence.  The neurons were turned on.  And so, the concept of δόξα can be pointed to by simply using the word.
Why is this important?  Because this immediate reuse of the word δόξα is articular.  And the article also has a pointing to function.  It’s not ‘glory’ abstractly considered.  It’s not even “the glory” that is out there somewhere.  It’s “the glory” that was just referred to.  It’s “this glory, the one I just said.”  So, the cognitive linguistic observation is that the “glory concept” neurons are already excited (and so, the concept is in focus), and the syntactic observation is that the author utilized the article to further highlight it.  This is why I suggest, “this glory” as an accurate translation.
And so, ‘glory’ is the propositional topic.  This means that ‘hope’ can’t be.
To summarize so far:  the phrase really doesn’t mean, “the hope of glory” as if ‘glory’ is some indefinite thing out in the future.  “Glory’ must be directly related to the mystery that surrounds the gospel message to the Gentiles.  That’s the ‘glory’ that Paul just used a few words earlier.
And, in that regard, δόξα, per Danker’s Concise Lexicon defines as, “the primary idea is one of ‘appearance’, then of ‘opinion’ based on what seems good or impressive, with ‘esteem’ as product.” [emphasis, mine]  That is, visibility is core to its meaning, and not the Olympic style ‘wow’ of achievement.  However, for μυστήριον, Danker has, “that which awaits disclosure of interpretation’.”  So, the phrase, τῆς δόξης τοῦ μυστηρίου τούτου, (the glory of this mystery) refers to that which is hidden being made surprisingly visible.  Using δόξα  and μυστήριον side-by-side is almost oxymoronic.  Paul describes this revelation as πλοῦτος (rich).  I mention this because it further highlights what would be going on in the Greek mind in a cognitive sense.  That is, how the mind is actually processing the language.  There’s a lot of superlative and seemingly contradictory things going on in the text itself.  The text itself makes visible something surprising (previously hidden).  So, the use of δόξα becomes rhetorical in its impact.  That which is visible becomes all the more visible.  So, δόξα is very much the propositional topic.
One last observation which admittedly is not directly related to your question, though it certainly relates to how Paul further defines what hope actually refers to.  The phrase, ὅ ἐστιν Χριστὸς ἐν ὑμῖν (which is Christ in you), note that the ὑμῖν is plural.  When the object of ἐν is plural, ἐν probably should be translated as ‘among’.  The idea of ‘in’ is certainly there, but the group is forefront, not the individual.  It’s that Christ is among the Gentiles.  That’s the surprising mystery.  God has greatly expanded who he is calling.  That’s the hope:  that the expansion would become ever increasingly visible.

You are correct in saying the phrase has already been used. τῆς δόξης is used three times in Colossians 1:11, 27 twice. But to say it is the same glory previously mentioned omits the first mention in 1:11. (All three are with the article.) The one in question is with ἡ ἐλπὶς in the nominative. The subject is ἡ ἐλπὶς the hope, not the glory. If you look back it should be to the glory of Him (1:11). That is the OT hiddenness of Christ made known by revelation among the Gentiles (1:27), similar to God with the Israelites when bringing them from Egypt.

@RevelationLad The Focus of a sentence and the Subject of the sentence are two different concepts.  The later is syntactic, the former relates to how information flows through a text.  Glory is in the attributive position, so I think an easy argument can be made that hope takes on an attribute of glory.  That's why I said that "glorious hope" is close in meaning.  But, what I wanted to bring out is how that hope, by way of information flow, defines that attribute.  IMO, we're talking subtleties here.  I think the referent in 1:11 is different, being related to God's might, not mystery.

The word δόξα (doxa) occurs three times in Col 1 as follows:

V11: the might of the glory of Him
V27a: the riches of the glory
V27b: the hope of the glory

This genitive form of the word glory is very popular with Paul who uses it frequently:

Rom 5:2 - hope of the glory of [the] Father
Rom 8:21 - the freedom of the glory
Rom 9:23 - the riches of the glory of Him
1 Cor 2:8 - the Lord of Glory
2 Cor 4:4 - the gospel of the glory of The Christ
2 Cor 4:6 - the knowledge of the glory of The God
2 Cor 4:17 - weight of glory
Eph 1:6 - praise of glory
Eph 1:12 - praise of glory of Him
Eph 1:14 - praise of glory of Him
Eph 1:17 - The Father of the glory
Eph 1:18 - the riches of the glory
Eph 3:16 - the riches of the glory
Phil 3:21 - the body of the glory of Him
1 Tim 1:11 - the gospel of the glory
etc

To this list we might also add some extras:

Matt 19:28 - throne of glory of Him
Matt 25:31 - throne of glory of Him
Acts 7:2 - the God of glory

All these ideas originate with some aspect of the glory of God and Jesus in the sense of His reputation of perfect righteousness.

Yes, but I know the term occurs, and occurs frequently. My question is about how it ought to be, or could be, translated into English, in the context of Colossians 1:27

@HAT - that is the point - the emphasis is on the noun "glory" it is not an adjective.  Thus "glorious hope" is the reverse (grammaticallY0 of the what the Greek text says.

... but sometimes those genitives are translated adjectivally. As in 1:11. Hence my question.

@HAT - I would nottranslate it like that - see my translation above.

So in Col. 1:11, "His glory's might" could be correct/more accurate, but "His glorious might" would not be correct/would be less accurate...?

@JedSchaaf - the only other way to translate it in English is to say, "His might's glory" using the English possessive.  The emphasis is on the "might"/"strength".  Just as someone "glories" in his might; ie, the reputation that the might brings.

"Of Him" = "His"; "of the glory" = "the glory's"; so together it would be "His glory's might"; i.e. the strength that His glory possesses. "His might's glory" would focus on the glory, not the might.

That's not what you have listed above for Col. 1:11, though...?

@JedSchaaf - sorry, I am getting flummoxed doing too many things at once.  The grammar is as I have listed above.  "His glory's might", or, "the might of glory of Him" is emphasizing the might that flows from His glory/reputation.  That is, God strength is in His righteousness and the reputation/glory that come from it.
